# How can I access value in deeply nested hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone help me to access `"value"` in this deeply nested hash:

```
hash = {
  "data" => {},
  "content" => [
    {
      "data" => {},
      "content" => [
        {
          "data" => {},
          "marks" => [],
          "value" => "est ce que j'arrive à te choper",
          "nodeType" => "text"
        }
      ],
      "nodeType" => "paragraph"
    }
  ],
  "nodeType" => "document"
}
```

Comment: what key you wanna access?

Comment: I try to access to "value"=>"est ce que j'arrive à te choper"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get value with [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

```
hash.dig('content', 0, 'content', 0, 'value')
#=> "est ce que j'arrive à te choper"
```

Comment: I would choose this too because this is one of the shortest if not the shortest solutions to this problem.